# Segue to a UITabBarViewController after some create account questions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have what I am calling a one time onboard set of UIViews that ask the user a couple questions to configure my iOS app correctly.

When the user has answered the onboarding questions I would like to segue to the UITabBarController Home screen, this is the same screen that will always appear every subsequent time the app opens after onboarding is complete. I do not have an Initial UIViewController set in my Storyboard, this, in my `AppDelegate` is how I go to the correct view, every time the app loads:

```
   self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if Settings.sharedInstance.onboardComplete{
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: baseTabBarStoryboardIdentifier) as! UITabBarViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    } else{
        self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: onboardStoryboardIdentifier) as! OnboardNavigationController
    }

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

This works fine, and I am able to load the `UITabBarViewController` which contains all my app's primary UIViews without any issues.

I would like to achieve this same "segue" from a UIButton `TouchUpInside` action. This segue would occur in a set of UIViews in a `UINavigationViewController` that has no connection to the main app UIViews contained in aforementioned UITabBarViewController, here is a screenshot of my Storyboard to give some context to this statement, you can see the onboarding UIViews circled in red, the main app UIViews contained in a UITabBarViewController are circled  in blue:

[image]

I have tried the same code as above in my AppDelegate in my UIButton action outlet implementation, I create a `UIWindow` instance, I get the `Storyboard`, I instantiate the `UITabBarViewController`, I set the `UIWindow rootViewController`. I am not able to figure out a way to transition to my main app `UITabBarViewController` after the user completes the Onboarding questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeController =  mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:baseTabBarStoryboardIdentifier) as! UITabBarViewController
appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = homeController
```